# If I just want a simple comment box below my entry, should I use Django's comment framework or write my own?

Tags: python, django, templates, frameworks

I'm split between writing my own comments model (pretty easy model, foreign key it to the entry) or using the full-out Django comment framework.

I mean, for right now, I just want a basic box for people to post a comment. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um... yes?

More seriously - whatever makes you happier. If you're in a hurry, roll your own; if you have a bit more time, by all means get to know the Django system; it'll probably be worthwhile in the longer run.